# Excel concatenate with IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

What I am trying to do is concatenate two cells, then check that concatenated value against a column of values, and put an X in a cell if such a value exists.  The following equation is what I'm using:

```
{=IF(CONCATENATE(A2, " ", B2) = 'MasterList'!$C:$C, "x", "")}
```

Column A is the name of the software and Column B the version number `(A="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1", B="4.5.50938", for example).` I know that this concatenated value exists on the MasterList worksheet so I don't understand why I'm not getting the answer I expect.

Gurus, what's my flaw here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest comparison/lookup on the worksheet is a MATCH function. If you have a long column to put this formula into you could try,

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2, " ", B2), 'MasterList'!$C:$C, 0)), "x", "")
```

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: Superb!  I knew there was a better way to go about it! Thanks for the assist Jeeped!

Answer (score 1):

I just want to say that before seeing this question, I had no idea what [array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7) were.

I have the following working example:

Sheet1:

```
A1: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1
B1: 4.5.50938

// press control-shift-enter after typing formula
C4: =IF(CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1)=Sheet2!$A:$A,"YAY","NAY")
```

Sheet2:

```
A1: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 4.5.50938
```

Not sure what the issue is with your spreadsheet. Do the values in `MasterList!$C:$C` actually correspond to what you expect as the result of the concatenation?

Comment: Truthfully I'm not sure why it wasn't equating like your example.  That's exactly what I was trying before I thought I needed an array formula (and I need to read-up, again, on them).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid array formula. The LHS is a single cell while the RHS is an array. What it actually does is compare the concatenation to **all cells** of columns `C` in `MasterList`.

You either need to make it a valid array formula or a normal formula. I recommend the second solution.

For the first solution, it should be:

```
{=IF(CONCATENATE(A:A, " ",B:B ) ='MasterList'!$C:$C, "x", "")}
```

However, this will be very slow because it will compute and concatenate two **full columns**, and moreover you will have to select your whole range where you want to calculate it (a full columns) then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

You can make it a simple formula in on cell then copy/paste along your column. Formula for `C2`:

```
=IF(CONCATENATE(A2, " ", B2) = 'MasterList'!$C2, "x", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seams that you select the entire column *C* on yout *MasterList*Sheet. Don't you mean just one cell? Like:

```
=IF(CONCATENATE(A2, " ", B2) = 'MasterList'!$C1, "x", "")
```

or try to : `=IF(CONCATENATE(A2, " ", B2) = MasterList.!$C1, "x", "")` (on open Office)

Best thing is instead of you write the Sheet name, let Excel do it for you by editing the formula, remove the sheet name and then with a mouse click navigate to the desired area.